# What is the difference between scope:{} and scope:true inside directive?

Tags: angularjs

I can't find this information about Angular.js and I notice while I was working that those two values work differently. What's the difference?

```
.directive('foo', function() {

  return {
    scope: true
  };
});

.directive('foo', function() {

  return {
    scope: {}
  };
});
```

Comment: Mmm, If I'm correct, scope=={} just checks id the scope is an empty object while true is just always true. What's exactly your doubt?

Comment: You're asking what is the difference between a boolean and an empty object ? And be carefull of the lame "==" check. Prefer "===" strict comparaison

Comment: @Bixi I'm asking about angular.js scope attribute.

Comment: @vidhya-sagar-reddy so you're the one out of context now :D

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Both `scope: true` and `scope:{}` will create a child scope for the directive. But,

`scope:true` will prototypically inherit the properties from the parent(say the controller where the directive comes under) where as `scope:{}` will not inherit the properties from the parent and hence called `isolated`

For instance lets say we have a controller c1 and two directives d1 and d2,

```
app.controller('c1', function($scope){
  $scope.prop = "some value";
});

.directive('d1', function() {
  return {
    scope: true
  };
});

.directive('d2', function() {
  return {
    scope: {}
  };
});

<div ng-controller="c1">
  <d1><d1>
  <d2><d2>
</div>
```

d1(scope:true) will have access to c1 scope -> prop where as d2 is isolated from the c1 scope.

**Note 1:** Both d1 and d2 will create a new scope for each directive defined.

**Note 2:** Apart from the difference between the two, for `scope:true` - Any changes made to the new child scope will not reflect back to the parent scope. However, since the new scope is inherited from the parent scope, any changes made in the c1 scope(the parent scope) will be reflected in the directive scope.

**Tip:** Use `scope:{}` or `isolated scope` for reusable angular directives. So that you won't end up messing with the parent scope properties

Answer (score 34):

**scope : true**

Angular JS will create a new scope by inheriting parent scope ( usually controller scope, else application’s root Scope ).

Note : Any changes made to this new scope will not reflect back to the parent scope. However, since the new scope is inherited from the parent scope, any changes made in the parent scope i.e. controller will be reflected in the directive scope.

**scope : false**

The controller and directive are using the same scope object. This means any changes to the controller or directive will be in sync.

**scope : {}**

New scope created for the directive, but it will not be inherited from the parent scope. This new scope also known as Isolated scope because it is completely detached from its parent scope.

Comment: A description with the same nicely broken down structure as the above answer in a few more words at [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/10/14/angular-directive-scope/).

Answer (score 4):

**scope: true** creates a new scope for the directive that inherits everything from the parents

**scope : {}** also creates a new scope for the directive, but it's isolated, so it doesn't inherit anything from the parents

Take a look a this article:

http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 3):

`scope: true` creates a scope that is not isolated from the parents scope, it inherits from the parents scope, while `scope: {}` creates a scope isolated from the parent.

Answer (score 2):

The 'scope' declaration in an AngularJS directive is a property of the 'Directive Definition Object', which is what's actually being returned by directive function that you define. The options for 'scope' are documented in the official angular documentation for a Directive Definition Object:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object

Here's the explanation taken directly from the documentation:

> #### scope
>
> The scope property can be false, true, or an object:
>
> **false** (default): No scope will be created for the directive. The
> directive will use its parent's scope.
>
> **true**: A new child scope that prototypically inherits from its parent
> will be created for the directive's element. If multiple directives on
> the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.
>
> **{...}** (an object hash): A new "isolate" scope is created for the
> directive's template. The 'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in
> that it does not prototypically inherit from its parent scope. This is
> useful when creating reusable components, which should not
> accidentally read or modify data in the parent scope. Note that an
> isolate scope directive without a template or templateUrl will not
> apply the isolate scope to its children elements.