# AngularJS Directives - What does "scope:{}" mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Take a look at this code snippet from my directive

```
return {
    controller: 'MyController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
        name: '=',
        id: '='
    },
    // ....
```

And then later in my view, I can use:

```
<div>{{ vm.name }}</div>
```

**My question is:** Why do we need to set `scope: {}` in the first place? If I remove, this the code breaks.

Note: If you're wondering why I have my bindings in `bindToController` instead of `scope`, I got the idea from this article (http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/).

Comment: which version you are using..it should be angular 1.4 +

Comment: @PankajParkar: Yup that's correct. I presume my solution will not work with 1.3.x?

Comment: correct in 1.3 it would be simply `bindToController: true`

Comment: Just a heads-up: the code above is missing a comma behind `controllerAs: 'vm'`. If that's also present in your codebase, you'll wanna fix it there too.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron ;) Fixed. No, wasn't missing in the original

Answer (score 1):

By default, unless explicitly set, directives don’t create their own scope. This can help you a bit more [What is the difference between scope:{} and scope:true inside directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528388/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-scopetrue-inside-directive).

Comment: Thanks @mic4eal. Just saw your edit. I'll check out the link

Comment: @Ricky, if you want more info then read the information provided by this article http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks @mic4eal; more clear to me now. So based on this, it would seem that `scope: {}` is the cleaner approach, because it's not coupled with the parent and hence does not rely on parent variables. Is this correct? I suppose if a directive were ALWAYS used with a parent, then `scope:true` would work... But just seems like it goes against the 'no coupling' paradigm

Comment: It depends if you want to be able to access variables from the parent scope. Simply, if you want to inherit the parent's variables.