# How to toggle a class on the component-DOM-node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I'm currently rewriting some older directives to the new component-syntax. One of my directives needs to toggle a class on the DOMnode.

```
<my-directive ng-class="$ctrl.getClassList()">
    <!-- DIRECTIVE CONTENT -->
</my-directive>
```

Now when I converted it into a component, this functionality no longer works. Is there some new functionality that I did not find? Or is this simply no longer possible?

```
<my-component ng-class="$ctrl.getClassList()">
    <!-- COMPONENT CONTENT -->
</my-component>
```

Thanks for taking the time!

---

To see a fully working (or better, **not** working) example you could check this snippet, or head to [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/h46ZOZv6c1UI0hzDN61C?p=preview)

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('plunker', []);
})(angular);

// DIRECTIVE
(function(angular) {
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .controller('MyDirectiveController', [function() {
      this.cssClass = '';
      this.toggle = function() {
        this.cssClass = (this.cssClass === '') ? 'active' : '';
      }
    }])
    .directive('myDirective', [function() {
      return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'MyDirectiveController',
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        template: '<button ng-class="$ctrl.cssClass" ng-click="$ctrl.toggle()">hit me baby one more time</button>'
      };
    }]);
})(angular);

// COMPONENT
(function(angular) {
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .controller('MyComponentController', [function() {
      this.cssClass = '';
      this.toggle = function() {
        this.cssClass = (this.cssClass === '') ? 'active' : '';
      }
    }])
    .component('myComponent', {
        controller: 'MyComponentController',
        template: '<button ng-class="$ctrl.cssClass" ng-click="$ctrl.toggle()">Do it again</button>'
    });
})(angular);
```

```css
my-directive, 
my-component {
  display: block;  
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0;  
}

my-directive.active,
my-component.active {
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 2em;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    border-color: darkred;
    
    border-width: 2px;
}
my-directive.active button,
my-component.active button {
  transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0;
  border: 1px solid;

  font-size: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
  background: inherit;
}

button.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.7"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-directive ng-class="$ctrl.cssClass"></my-directive>
    <my-component ng-class="$ctrl.cssClass"></my-component>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a component is the same as a creating a directive with isolated scope ([What is the difference between scope:{} and scope:true inside directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528388/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-scopetrue-inside-directive)). If you change your directive withe a scope of {} you will see that it also doesn't work.

The .active class is set only on the button, not on the component html tag.

I changed your plunker to showcase the issue:

```
// COMPONENT
(function(angular) {
  angular
    .module('plunker')
    .controller('MyComponentController', [function() {
      this.cssClass = '';
      this.toggle = function() {
        this.cssClass = (this.cssClass === '') ? 'active' : '';
      }
    }])
    .component('myComponent', {
        controller: 'MyComponentController',
        template: '<div class="my-component" ng-class="$ctrl.cssClass"><button ng-click="$ctrl.toggle()">{{$ctrl.cssClass}}Do it again</button></div>'
    });
})(angular);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/qscGAIjNqQY06hAcnsRM?p=preview

Als this [structure guide](https://github.com/kevinvanhove/angular-structure-styleguide) may help you think differently about components.

Comment: I found out that I haven't replied to your answer. But I have now indeed fixed it through events to toggle classes on the outer-node in my states.