# Trying to send the values from HTML to controller

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to send the values from html to controller but is not goes to controller. What is the problem with this code value is show undefined at controller and factory. I hope this code is easy understood:

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, loginfactory) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        var promise = loginfactory.logincheck($scope.userid, $scope.pwd);
    }
});
mymodal.factory("loginfactory", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        "logincheck": function(userid, pwd) {
            console.log(userid);
            console.log(pwd);
            return Object;
        }
    };
});
mymodal.directive('modal', function() {
    return {
        template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
            '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="">×</button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude=""></div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.title = attrs.title;
            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value) {
                if (value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });
            $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });
            $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My view:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
    <h1>Modal example</h1>
    <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button>
    <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="userid" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="doLogin()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </modal>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need service neither directive! just pass `ng-click="doLogin(userid, pwd)"` in controller `$scope.doLogin = function(userid, pwd){$http.post('yourApiUrl',{userId:userid,pwd:pwd})}`

Comment: but i want to used these bootstrap toggle popup  which is possible by directive only

Comment: Sorry I meant what you need to adjust is in your view `ng-click="doLogin(userid, pwd)"` in controller `$scope.doLogin = function(userid, pwd){$http.post('yourApiUrl',{userId:userid,pwd:pwd})}` you can keep your service and directive. No problem.

Comment: not it will not work because userid and pwd are undefine error is occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I mean [see Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9UnvQNvOmkm3Sz1p4FzN?p=preview);
In your directive you used: `scope: true,` this mean what is change in the directive will not reflect on the parent scope [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528388/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-scopetrue-inside-directive) so to get it works you have to do like this.  in the submit btton: (angular best practice passing scope from view)

```
<button  ng-click="doLogin(userid,pwd)" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
```

in your controler:

```
$scope.doLogin = function(userid,pwd) {
    var promise = loginfactory.logincheck(userid, pwd);
}
```

you see I don't pass $scope.userid and $scope.pwd in your `loginfactory` but pass the value from view because of `scope: true,` make your code won't work.

one last suggest, you can use UI bootstrap for angular so you don't have to mix with jquery bootstrap. [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)