# How to get correct attributes of a directive that is used multiple times on the same page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

*Angular 1.4.8*

[Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergibondarenko/y61rca5e/2/).

I have a directive used twice on one page. I only change some attributes of the directive. It appears, that I get only the last defined attributes inside `searchRelations` function.

Is it possible to get relations A attributes when I search in the first text input and get relations B attributes when I search in the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
scope: true
```

in your directive, otherwise, they both share the parent one.

Answer (score 1):

As @ssougnez said

```
scope: true
```

The important difference between setting it to true instead to {} is 
that the new scope will prototypically inherit the properties from the parent scope. 
More explanation here:

[What is the difference between scope:{} and scope:true inside directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528388/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-and-scopetrue-inside-directive)

Answer (score 1):

I broke the `search-bar` directive into a self contained thing, that has it's own isolate scope, as well as cleans up your template. Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/y61rca5e/5/

This totally worked!

Comment: Hello, I tested the provided JSFiddle by adding `scope: true` and it totally worked as well... Just have a look at the console and you'll see that the logged message contains "relationA" for the first input and "relationB" for the second one... So what do you mean by "it didn't totally work" ?

Comment: @frosty your solution will give access to "path" but I think what the author of the question need is also access to parent scope which I think he will loose as your element directive creates a new isolated scope